# Skorokhod Embedding theorem proof

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

It occurs in Durrett's proof of Skorokhod embedding that he needs the following.

Suppose that we have a Brownian motion $B_t$ in $1$-d that starts at $0$. (To be clear, it is not necessarily constructed on the Wiener space, but I do require it to be everywhere continuous.  With that assumption, then we have that $T_{b, a}=\inf\{t\geq 0 : B_t \notin (a, b)\}$ is a stopping time wrt the standard right continuous (RC) filtration.)  If $U, V$ are RVs with $U\geq0$ and $V\leq0$ then supposedly the function $T_{U, V}$ is measurable. (with respect to the original sigma algebra for which $U, V$ are RVs.)  Notice that this does not make it a stopping time.

I need help with that.

He also then uses the optional stopping theorem for continuous RC martingales with RC filtrations.  This theorem implies that if $T$ is the stopping time and $X_t$ is the martingale, then $X_T$ is measurable wrt the sigma algebra of the stopping time $T$ and also for all $t\geq0$ we have $X_T=E(X_t\mid \mathfrak{F}_T)$ on $\{T<t\}$ a.s.

Durrett only says that by conditioning on the values of $(U, V)$, we can apply this to our situation above to conclude that (By now he has already started assuming the measurability of $T_{U, V}$.)

$$E(T_{U, V})=E\lbrace E(T_{U, V}\mid (U, V))\rbrace=E(-UV).$$

He has already shown that $E(T_{b,a})=-ab$.  Where I object is it seems like his manipulation is "treating $U, V$ as constant" just because they are the subject of being "conditioned upon."  I don't understand this, especially since $U, V$ are allowed to take values in continua.

(For those with the book, see p. 384 and the surrounding.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\in\mathcal X$ and $Y\in\mathcal Y$ be independent random elements on some joint probability space.

You can rewrite Fubini's theorem as: for every measurable function $f:\mathcal X\times \mathcal Y\to\mathbb R$ $$\mathbb E(f(X,Y)|X=x) =\mathbb  Ef(x,Y).$$

So for your case as $B_{T_{U,V}}$ is a function of the two random elements $B_t\in C^0(\mathbb R)$ and $(U,V)\in\mathbb R^2$ we have

$$\mathbb E\left(\left. B_{T_{U,V}} \right|U=u,V=v\right) = \mathbb E\left(B_{T_{u.v}} \right). $$

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how this applies here, but first of all does it imply measurability?

Comment: @Jeff Measurability of what with respect to what?

Comment: $T_{U, V}$ with respect to the underlying sigma algebra.

Comment: $[T_{U,V} <t] = \bigcup_{\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb Q} [\alpha < V < U < \beta]\cap[T_{\beta,\alpha}<t]$

Comment: I don't think this is quite right.  I'm toying with replacing your union with intersections, and strict with nonstrict inequalities.  As it stands, the problem is that perhaps some path exist $(U, V)$ but not anything more.  Don't forget that because this is a question of measurability, null sets matter. (Because there's not even a notion of null set until you put the probability measure in.)  So BMs are just paths that start somewhere, and they can have local max/min.

Comment: I believe this works $\{T_{U, V}\leq t\}=\bigcap_{\alpha<\beta \in \mathbb{Q}}[(\{V<\alpha<\beta<U\}\cap\{T_{\beta, \alpha}\leq t \})\cup\{U\leq \beta\}\cup\{V\geq \alpha\}]$ provided that $U, V$ are legitimately nonnegative and nonpositive respectively and the BM is continuous.

Comment: So this actually works for a continuous process in 1-dimension because without referring to the measure, that's all a "BM" is.

Comment: Now it is time for me to try to understand the meat of your answer.    I'm a bit confused there because I don't have independence of $U, V$ and furthermore the notation $B_{T_{U, V}}$ is deceptive because it actaully accepts (the same) input $\omega$ in 4 places.  At $\omega$ it evaluates to $B_{T_{U(\omega), V(\omega)}(\omega)}(\omega)$ so maybe I am misunderstanding your method but I don't see how 2 independent variables relates to our case.

Comment: @Jeff I think I get your confusion. In the Skorohod embedding theorem $U$ and $V$ are not defined on the same probability space as $B_t$. So I've just used the product space, which makes measurability easy. Skorohod is not true for random variables defined on the same space as the Brownian motion.

Comment: Also you should also check that my formula for $T_{U,v}$ holds as long as $B_t$ is continuous. It's worth trying understand why null sunfortunately is not something I explain in a comment.